# Output of 'cat' to find files with partial filenames

Tags: bash

Say I've file1.txt with

```
ptext1
ptext2
ptext3
ptext4
```

These are the partial file names (library names) which I'm trying to find from a directory. Something like

```
cat file1.txt | xargs find . -name "*$0*"
```

or say,

```
cat file.txt | awk '{system("find . -name " *$0*)}'
```

None of them are working.
Please suggest.

Comment: xargs appends the standard input to the command passed; it does not set $0 (but your shell may expand that when it parses the line), so your idea doesn't work. xargs may also append more than one input word at the same time, which you have to suppress with `-n 1`. Instead of xargs you can simply say `foreach file in $(cat file1.txt); do find -name "*$file*"; done` or such.

Comment: Always try and avoid **UUOc** (Unnecessary User Of `cat`). Virtually every use of **cat pipe** or `cat | foo` can be done in a way that avoids the unnecessary spawning of a subshell with `cat`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Pretty sure its `useless use of cat` !

Comment: Hah, I like it. If my fat fingers hadn't gotten in the way it would have been **UUOc** (Unnecessary Use Of cat), but I'll take (Useless Use Of cat) as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but you could always loop over and run `find` on each:

**Update to reflect suggestions in comments**

```
while read -r filename; do
  find . -type f -name "*$filename*"
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: Not necessarily more elegant but faster, if that's an issue, would be to assemble a `find` command line which looks like `find -name <pattern1> -o -name <pattern2> ...`. Calling find each time is a significant overhead if the actual search is short.

Comment: Just in case there are goofy file/path names `read -r` may help. You may also want to add `-type f` to eliminate matching dirs with the find command.

Answer (score 1):

One way with xargs

```
xargs -I{} find . -name "*"{}"*"  < file
```